# pkg Installation failed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ventura, pkg

I am trying to install via a pkg file and it keeps failing.

- Ventura 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)
- Brave Browser is the item being installed

I accidently told the os to block install when it asked for permissions. I do not know where to reset the permission in order to run the installer successfully. It strickly tells me the installation failed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with Ventura. I found this solution that was to copy the installer to the Desktop, and it installed successfully.

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/install-with-pkg-file-failed.2367425/?post=31777065#post-31777065